# How can I create an SSL certificate for my .NET Core web app with my IP Address as the App URL?

Tags: .net, ssl, asp.net-core, https, iis-express

I'd like to be able to run my .NET Core web application locally with my IP Address as the App URL so I can receive external requests. The only issue is the site has an invalid SSL certificate. The certificate by default is for 'localhost', which is not going to work in my case.

I was able to successfully create a test certificate using my computer's name following Scott Hanselman's blog post on the subject. However, if I attempt to create a certificate using my IP Address the certificate is invalid. I've looked through many other posts here on StackOverflow but haven't found anything that's helped out so far.

I'm really not sure how to approach the issue and have hit a wall, any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How often do you see a production service using “my IP Address as the App URL”? Real world applications use domain names. BTW, Jexus Manager can help generate self-signed certificates, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html while a CA is needed to get real certificates.

Comment: I’m aware production services don’t us IP Addresses. This is for testing. Thanks for the link I’ll check this out

Comment: Any self-signed certificate will be showing a warning. Only certificates from CA (Certificate authorities) don't show. And the pretty much only free one is letsencrypt, which requires you have a domain, not ip

Comment: It's not possible to get a cert for an IP, self-signed or not. Certs are expressly for domains to legitimize the owner and the attachment of that domain. IPs are technically already identified (though in practice, because of large scale hosting providers, it can be vague who the actual "owner" is). If you can't or won't get a cert through an official CA (because you don't a public domain attached, perhaps), then your only option is to self-sign for the hostname, and then add the self-signed cert to the trusted stores of all clients that need to access it.

Comment: I have the same problem for two applications running on 2 computers in intranet, that have to communicate over https. Would be possible to add entries in etc/hosts and then use them as "pseudo"-dns names for the certificates?